# Delete a post with Vue + Laravel + Fetch

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fetch

Hi I am trying to delete a post but it is not working at all, when I check the url in the browser it displays a blank page:

So my api route in Laravel is:

```
Route::resource('/bank', 'BankController');
```

My HTML code which it's inside a component:

```
<button v-on:click="deletePost(post.bank_id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm">
  <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

The vue code is:

```
methods: {
    deletePost: function (id) {
        fetch('/api/bank/'+ id)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
    }
 },
```

When I click:

It displays a blank page if I do that by URL but the console shows:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

what could it be?

Comment: it seems your API doesn't return correct JSON

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur is it correct all?

Comment: You should call the api with `DELETE` method.

Comment: But @ElektaKode in Laravel that is the delete method for api

Comment: Post the code of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it worked.. it was this:

```
fetch('/api/bank/' + id,  {
  method: 'DELETE'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change request method to DELETE while using resource.

In case fetch does not support delete method, try this spoofing trick:

```
fetch('/api/bank/'+ id + '?_method=delete')
```

Moreover, I recommend you to use axios in vuejs instead of fetch.